# kendo grid, change text of custom button

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

Does anyone know how to change text of custom button in Kendo UI, when it is defined like:

`c.Command(command =>
        {command.Custom("custom").Click("Action").Text("Text");
})`

in order to after click on that button, the text could change.

thanks in advance for answers.

Comment: That should work, does it not?

Comment: It works but in other way that want. I found way to connect it with model property `command.Custom("custom").Click("Action").Text(@Model.Text);` but because binding is in the same fragment of code it does not work properly and gives error: 'Cannot perform runtime binding on a null reference'. How to perform binding eariler?

Comment: It would be helpful if you could post some more of your view, ideally the entire thing.  If not, at least the top and then your grid.

Answer (score 0):

Using your sample code,

- The `"custom"` parameter is useless/ignored by the parser (leaving nothing means `"custom"`)
- the `Click("")` parameter is the name of a Javascript function that will be executed upon a click
- The `Text("")` parameter is the default text (when Razor is executed/page loads)

```
c.Command(command =>{command.Custom("custom").Click("Action").Text("Text");})
```

you'd need a function like:

```
function Action(e) {
    e.target[0].innerText = "Some new text for the button"
}
```